# How do I gain Boost?

Tags: tribes-ascend

In the end-game screen, there is one item that says: "Boost : Not earned"

It doesn't show any progress, either.

How do I earn a Boost?

Comment: You buy an XP booster for gold.

Comment: You could post that as an answer, actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can buy boosts with Tribes gold. The cost and time the boost lasts are:

[image]

(The $30 and $50 packages used to include a free boost, but the boost was removed in lieu of more gold.)

A good point to keep in mind is that making *any* real-money purchase will give your account VIP status, which permanently increases your XP gain by 50%. This stacks with the boost bonus: Being boosted (2x) and a VIP (1.5x) will **triple** the amount of XP you would normally gain.

Answer (score 0):

XP Boosters can be bought with Tribes Gold in the in-game store.